# Referencing own publications one per one

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

In my thesis that I'm writing using LyX 2.1.4 I'd like to include a section with references to my own publications in specific manual order and with paragraphs describing the content. Current I know only how to \cite these publications, but not how to insert the full reference as how it looks like in the generated Bibliography. Ideally and naively, I would like to use a command like \print{exampleKey}

I use BibDesk for bibliography management, having two bib files: 1) "bibliography.bib" for general citations and 2) "own-bibliography.bib" for own publications. I'm able to separate the references under different headings in Bibliography section, using bibtex.

Current LYX minimal sample file: https://gist.github.com/paveljasek/77ece95b897e89c885f8354dc6086fd9

How I want the section to look like:
[image: required state]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add your code to your answer instead of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `biblatex` and not the old `BibTeX`. An example with `xelatex` and Unicode:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
my work: \fullcite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

needs `xelatex` - `biber` - `xelatex` However, LyX should do it by default. You can enable the use of Biber in the configurations.